# Hybrid Node module with both a main and a module entry in package.json

Tags: node.js, es6-modules, commonjs

```
  "name": "@private-owner/tracking",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Library which provides JS helper methods for GoogleAnalytics and DataWarehouse tracking",
  "main": "dist/tracking.cjs",
  "module": "dist/tracking.esm.js",
  "repository": "https://github.com/@private-owner/tracking",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": false,
  "type": "module",
```

I'm trying to make a library we use internally compatible with both ESM and CJS.
Will the solution above work? Can I have these two fields ( `main` , `module` ) at the same time present? I read that the recommended approach is to have a conditional export field, a bit like:

```
{
  "exports": {
    "import": "./index-import.js",
    "require": "./index-require.cjs"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

Is the above necessary?